# Passing strings to new file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script that while it runs it will also create a new script.
The second script in the end should include those lines:

```
$line1 = 'some string' 
$line2 = 'some string'
Start-Process $line1 -Arguments $line2
```

I've tried passing it from the 1st script using the code:

```
$lines = "$line1 = 'some string'", "$line2 = 'some string'"
foreach ($line in $lines) | Add-Content -Path script2
```

Which does not works since the var parts are dropped and I'm left with the '= some string' only.

Comment: Please read the help about asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Escape the dollars with backtick or use single quoted strings and escape the inner single-quotes.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell expands variables inside double-quoted strings. Since `$line1` and `$line2` are undefined in your second code snippet they're expanded to empty strings. Either escape the `$` characters with backticks:

```
$lines = "`$line1 = 'some string'", "`$line2 = 'some string'"
```

or use single quotes as the outer and double quotes as the inner quotes (variables aren't expanded in single-quoted strings):

```
$lines = '$line1 = "some string"', '$line2 = "some string"'
```

I would recommend using a here-string instead of a string array for defining code snippets in code, though, as that improves readability:

```
$lines = @'
$line1 = "some string"
$line2 = "some string"
'@
```

Also, `foreach ($line in $lines) | Add-Content` does not work and will throw an error, because [`foreach` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29148462/1630171) don't write to the pipeline, so `Add-Content` doesn't get any input. Just pipe `$lines` directly into `Add-Content`:

```
$lines | Add-Content 'C:\output.ps1'
```