# Out of memory exception on [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText with large CSV

Tags: powershell, ssis-2012

I have a simple PowerShell script that replaces "false" or "true" with "0" or "1":

```
$InputFolder = $args[0];
if($InputFolder.Length -lt 3)
{
    Write-Host "Enter a path name as your first argument" -foregroundcolor Red
    return
}
if(-not (Test-Path $InputFolder)) {
    Write-Host "File path does not appear to be valid" -foregroundcolor Red
    return
}
Get-ChildItem $InputFolder
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($InputFolder).Replace("`"false`"", "`"0`"").Replace("`"true`"", "`"1`"").Replace("`"FALSE`"", "`"0`"").Replace("`"TRUE`"", "`"1`"")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($InputFolder, $content)
[GC]::Collect()
```

This works fine for almost all files I have to amend, with the exception of one 808MB CSV.
I have no idea how many lines are in this CSV, as nothing I have will open it properly.

Interestingly, the PowerShell script will complete successfully when invoked manually via either PowerShell directly or via command prompt.
When this is launched as part of the SSIS package it's required for, that's when the error happens.

Sample data for the file:

```
"RowIdentifier","DateProfileCreated","IdProfileCreatedBy","IDStaffMemberProfileRole","StaffRole","DateEmploymentStart","DateEmploymentEnd","PPAID","GPLocalCode","IDStaffMember","IDOrganisation","GmpID","RemovedData"     
"134","09/07/1999 00:00","-1","98","GP Partner","09/07/1999 00:00","14/08/2009 15:29","341159","BRA 871","141","B83067","G3411591","0"
```

Error message thrown:

[image: PowerShell Error Message]

I'm not tied to PowerShell - I'm open to other options. I had a cribbed together C# script previously, but that died on small files than this - I'm no C# developer, so was unable to debug it at all.

Any suggestions or help gratefully received.

Comment: How big is your CSV that you're running out of memory??

Comment: why not read it a section at a time, Make a temp folder for bigger files then copy them back to original folder and delete temp? Is that a ok solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Generally, avoiding read large files all at once, as you can run out of memory, as you've experienced.
- Instead, process text-based files *line by line* - both reading and writing.

  - While PowerShell generally excels at line-by-line (object-by-object) processing, it it is *slow* with files with many lines.
  - Using the .NET Framework directly - while more complex - offers much better performance.
- If you process the input file line by line, you cannot directly write back to it and must instead write to a *temporary output file*, which you can replace the input file with on success.

Here's a solution that uses .NET types directly for performance reasons:

```
# Be sure to use a *full* path, because .NET typically doesn't have the same working dir. as PS.
$inFile = Convert-Path $Args[0]      
$tmpOutFile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()

$tmpOutFileWriter = [IO.File]::CreateText($tmpOutFile)
foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile)) {
  $tmpOutFileWriter.WriteLine(
    $line.Replace('"false"', '"0"').Replace('"true"', '"1"').Replace('"FALSE"', '"0"').Replace('"TRUE"', '"1"')
  )
}
$tmpOutFileWriter.Dispose()

# Replace the input file with the temporary file.
# !! BE SURE TO MAKE A BACKUP COPY FIRST.
# -WhatIf *previews* the move operation; remove it to perform the actual move.
Move-Item -Force -LiteralPath $tmpOutFile $inFile -WhatIf
```

Note:

- UTF-8 encoding is assumed, and the rewritten file will *not* have a BOM. You can change this by specifying the desired encoding to the .NET methods.
- As an aside: Your chain of `.Replace()` calls on each input line can be simplified as follows, using PowerShell's `-replace` operator, which is case-*insensitive*, so only *2* replacements are needed:
  `$line -replace '"false"', '"0"' -replace '"true"', '"1"'`
  However, while that is shorter to *write*, it is actually *slower* than the `.Replace()` call chain, presumably because `-replace` is *regex*-based, which incurs extra processing.

Comment: `foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inFile)) {`  I'm pretty sure [that's still going to read the entire file into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230828/696808).  I would probably create a StreamReader and a StreamWriter and do it that way.

Comment: @BaconBits: I don't think so, because `.ReadLines()` returns a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`, which PowerShell's `foreach` loop happily lazily enumerates. ["When you use `ReadLines`, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_). The linked answer doesn't apply here.

Comment: @BaconBits: I realized I had so far merely _assumed_ that lazy enumeration would occur, but here's a command to prove it: `$f=[IO.path]::GetTempFileName(); '-- creating file...'; 1..1e5 > $f; '-- reading 10 lines...'; $i=0; $enum = [IO.File]::ReadLines($f); foreach ($line in $enum) { if ($i++ -eq 10) {break}; "[$line]" }; $enum.Dispose(); ri $f`. The fact that the `foreach` loop prints the first 10 lines virtually instantaneously implies that the 100,000-lines file was _not_ read in full first, i.e., it implies that the enumeration was indeed lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file Per line with **get-content -readcount**, **Out-file** a temp file, then delete old file and **rename-item** the temp file the old files name.

Small things that would need fixing. This will add a new empty line at end of file. This will change the encoding. You could try and get the current file encoding and set the encoding on the **Out-file -encoding**

```
function Replace-LargeFilesInFolder(){
    Param(
        [string]$DirectoryPath,
        [string]$OldString,
        [string]$NewString,
        [string]$TempExtention = "temp",
        [int]$LinesPerRead = 500
    )
    Get-ChildItem $DirectoryPath -File | %{
        $File = $_
        Get-Content $_.FullName -ReadCount $LinesPerRead |
            %{
                $_ -replace $OldString, $NewString | 
                out-file "$($File.FullName).$($TempExtention)" -Append
            }
        Remove-Item $File.FullName
        Rename-Item "$($File.FullName).$($TempExtention)" -NewName $($File.FullName)
    }
}

Replace-LargeFilesInFolder -DirectoryPath C:\TEST -LinesPerRead 1 -OldString "a" -NewString "5"
```

Comment: Can this be adjusted to do multiple changes at once, or would I need to do multiple runs against the same file?