# Why am I getting the warning "The variable 'lastUpdate' is assigned but never used." in this PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, scope

In this piece of code I'm getting a "UseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments" warning from PSScriptAnalyzer

```
$lastUpdate = $false;
$shouldUpdate = $false;
if (Test-Path $logfile) {
    (Get-Content $logfile) | Where-Object {
        $_ -match "([^-]*)->\s*UpdateCheck"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $lastUpdate = $Matches[1]
    }
    if ($lastUpdate) {
        $shouldUpdate = (Get-Date $Matches[1]) -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))
    } else {
        $shouldUpdate = $true;
    }
}
```

The variable that triggers the warning is `$lastUpdate` in this line:

```
$lastUpdate = $Matches[1]
```

despite the fact that it's used int the next line.

Is this a problem with my code - I'm guessing it has something to do with scope and the `ForEach-Object` loop - or is the problem with PSScriptAnalyzer in VSCode?

Comment: i show the same incorrect "not used" msg for both `ShouldUpdate` and for `$LastUpdate`. to me, it looks like a bug. my setup >>> VSC = 1.36.1 & posh ext = 2019.5.0 & posh = 5.1 & os = win7x64 ///// it shows on a number of my other scripts, also.

Comment: I have reported the same bug under issue [#1164](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1163), as far as I can tell PSScriotAnalyzer should exclude all the standard cmdlets that run in the current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the bug is issued at [#1164](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1163)

As a workaround you might consider using the `ForEach` statement rather than the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (see: [Difference between ForEach and ForEach-Object in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29148462/1701026)):

```
ForEach ($Item in ((Get-Content $logfile) | Where-Object {$_ -match "([^-]*)->\s*UpdateCheck"})) {
    $lastUpdate = $Matches[1]
}
```

In your case, you might even able to simplify your statement to just:

```
$lastUpdate = (Get-Content $logfile) | Where-Object {$_ -match "([^-]*)->\s*UpdateCheck"}
```

In this example `$lastUpdate` refers to a colection of matches which will cast to `$True` if it contains one or more items and to `$False` if it doesn't contain any matches.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that forEach ≠ ForEach-Object. Thanks. As far as the second snippet goes, I want $lastUpdate to equal the last instance of the match in the logfile, would that snippet work correctly if there were multiple matches?

Comment: Yes, it should, I have added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's better than a workaround, it's an improvement. So I could use `$lastUpdate = (Get-Content $logfile) | Where-Object {$_ -match "([^-]*)->\s*UpdateCheck"}; if ($lastUpdate){$lastupdate = $lastUpdate[-1]}`