# Powershell list only match part of filename

Tags: powershell, match

I have a single folder filled with PDF's, all their filenames contain a Pxxx-xx number.

Examples:

```
"P418-04 hingeblock.pdf"
"P293-21 corner profile.pdf"
"P810-18 bench support.pdf
"R5511-01 coat hook.pdf"
```

I want to create a folder structure based on these numbers and place every file inside its own folder.

I figured out how to create the folders using a sample folder structure when I have the matches:

```
$ItemNames | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ChildItem -Path ("$TargetPath\000 Sample Folder") | Copy-Item -Destination ("$TargetPath\$_") -Recurse -Container
```

I get as far as selecting the files:

```
Get-Item -Path ("$SourcePath") | ls | where Name -match '[PR]\d?\d\d\d-?\d?\d?'
```

Only, how do i make it list ONLY the matching part of the filename instead of the entire filepath?

"Get-Item" always show s a list with columns "mode", "lastwritetime" and "name" and outputs the full filelocation.

I only want a simple list of:

```
P418-04
P293-21
P810-18
R5511-01
```

So I can use that list to create the folder names.

Comment: Try `^(?:.*/)?'[PR]\d{3,4}-?\d{0,2}(?:\.\w+)?$'`. Maybe you need `\d{3}-\d{2}` instead of `\d{3,4}-?\d{0,2}` acc. to your description.

Comment: PLEASE, show two or three sample file names and the desired dir names you want from those items. you have not shown enuf detail about the inputs to test code ... [*grin*]

Comment: `Get-Item -Path ("$SourcePath") | ls` this seems extremely unnecessary. `ls` is already an alias of `Get-ChildItem` and without `Get-Item` it would do the same thing. Do `Get-ChildItem $SourcePath`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$prefixes = Get-ChildItem "Filepath" -Directory | Foreach {$_.Name.ToString().Split(" ")[0]}
```

Now `$prefixes` will contain those beggining pattern matches.

Comment: `$_.Name` is already a string, so there is no need for `ToString()` there. As aside, for newcomers, it is helpful not to shorten `ForEach-Object` into `ForEach`, because there is always much confusion between the two ([Difference between foreach and ForEach-Object in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148614/9898643))