# in jenkins(windows), powershell ls pipeline get null

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

This is my jenkins script.
Without pipeline, can see ls result list.
but when include pipeline with foreach,  assign null to '$_'. Why??

```
stage('Module Build'){
    gitlabCommitStatus('Module Build'){
        powershell "${pythonPath} -m compileall ${srcPath}"
        powershell "ls ${srcPath}\\*.py -Recurse | foreach {rm $_}"
    }
}
```

error log

```
d:\...\durable-51664e76\powershellScript.ps1:1 char:33
+ ls src\*.py -Recurse | foreach {rm "null"}

+                                 ~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Jenkins\work...istributor\nu 

   ll:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov 

   eItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing syntax to foreach-object

```
 powershell "ls ${srcPath}\\*.py -Recurse | %{rm $_}"
```

**further reading:**
[Difference between ForEach and ForEach-Object in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)